# Get Azure AD Administrator Programatically

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to find a way to check the AD roles attached to a user. After a lot of reading, it seems like there is no cli call that can provide this information. The workaround I am thinking is to list out all the users who have "Global Administrator" permission in the AD role. Is there an azure CLI call that can help with getting this information? I tried the calls in `az ad user` but none of them have the information I am looking for.

Comment: Just because there's no CLI tool doesn't mean you can't do this programmatically through the HTTP API. The command line tools use the HTTP API too. There's no other way to communicate with a service that actually runs in the cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with *@Panagiotis Kanavos*, you can make use of **HTTP requests** by calling them from Azure CLI.

You can use below **MS Graph** query to get the list the users with ***Global Administrator*** role:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignments?$filter=roleDefinitionId eq '62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10'
```

To call the above query from **Azure CLI**, you can use **`az rest`** command like below:

```bash
az rest --method get --url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignments?$filter=roleDefinitionId eq '62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10'"
```

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have below users in my tenant, assigned with ***Global Administrator*** role:

[image]

To get these results from **Azure CLI**, I ran below command:

```bash
az rest --method get --url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignments?$filter=roleDefinitionId eq '62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10'"
```

**Response:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/list-role-assignments-users) is Powershell and Graph API example how you can do that.